# How to open and read particular files on iOS (.xpt .por)?

Tags: ios

What apps on iOS can open .xpt and .por files? I think they are called binary or stata/sas files in general? How do you open them on iOS? Is that not possible?

Comment: Are you looking for existing app which can open these files (then please add some more information about the system/application creating them in the first place) or for ways on how to develop such an ap?

Comment: Looking for existing app to open files as i don't know how to code... Not sure what system etc created the files, tho, they are just files downloadable off internet.

Answer (score 1):

.xpt files are SAS XPORT files; .por files are ascii data files created by SPSS.

[StatsGuru for SPSS](https://itunes.apple.com/app/id807503793) is a iOS app:

> Stats Guru is a tool to help social scientists determine the correct
>   statistical test for their data. The tool then provides a walk-through
>   for each test, using SPSS Version 21.

[SAS Mobile BI](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/sas-mobile-bi/id511030524?mt=8) is an iOS app.

> SAS® Mobile BI empowers decision makers with business reports and
>   dashboards anywhere, anytime! SAS Mobile BI, part of the SAS® Visual
>   Analytics solution, enables you to access and interact with reports
>   and report elements such as graphs, tables, KPIs, and data grids.